# In 22.04.03 LTS, Save & Open Dialog Reverts to Alphabetical Order When Doing a Text Search, Also Overrides Directory-First Order

Tags: 22.04, gtk3, dialog

In 22.04.03 LTS, Save & Open Dialog Reverts to Alphabetical Order When Doing a Text Search

I have noticed a major quality-of-life issue with the upgrade to 22, which is making it much more time-consuming to navigate through directories using the keyboard in the Save... and Open... Dialog boxes. I have almost all my directories set to be ordered by Date Modified, with the checkbox selected to show directories first, so that I can quickly navigate to the directories I use most often when saving or opening files.

In the past, if I would type characters of the beginning of the name of the directories, the focus would jump to one of these directories and then I could use the up and down arrows to navigate in the box. The order would be preserved **and** directories would stay first.

Now, it performs a full-text search, which is a problem in and of itself (I would prefer it to only jump to the first character as it did before, i.e. search only from the beginning of the word not full-text search), but what is more frustrating than the fact that it is performing this unwanted search, is that it is now changing the order to be alphabetical.

Furthermore, it also turns off the directory-first setting and shows files before directories if they occur first in alphabetical order.

This screenshot shows the order that I have selected:

[image: Screenshot showing sort by date modified]

This screenshot shows the dialog switching to alphabetical order as I type a single character:

[image: Screenshot showing text search for letter a reverting to alphabetical order]

This screenshot, showing slightly changed directory names to illustrate the other point, shows it displaying the files before the directories, overriding that setting:

[image: Screenshot showing text search for a letter overriding directory-first order]

How can I get this dialog to behave as desired? I want the order to stay the same including both whatever order I have selected for the directory (such as date modified descending) **and** the settings such as showing directories first.

It would be even better if I could also turn off full-text search and search only from the beginning of the word, although this is less important to me than getting my settings for the order preserved/respected during the search.